# Custom legend based on color of bars in a dc.js composite chart

Tags: d3.js, legend, dc.js

I implemented a composite chart with two bar charts in which one bar chart consists of bars with different colored bars. 
Now, I want to create a custom legend that represents each color bar (similar to https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/pie-external-labels.html used for pie chart).
Below is the code snippet of what I've done so far:

```
var buttonPress = dc.barChart(composite)
    .dimension(joyTimeDimension)
    //.renderlet(colorRenderlet)
    //.colors('red')
    .colors(colorbrewer.Set1[5])
    .colorDomain([101, 105])
    .colorAccessor(function (d) {
        return d.value;
    })
    .group(btnGroup, "Button Press")
    .keyAccessor(function(d) {return d.key[0];})
    .valueAccessor(function (d) {
        return d.value;
    })
    .title( function(d){ 
        return [
            "Time: "+d.key[0],
            "button Name: "+d.key[1],
            "button: "+ d.value
        ].join('\n')
    });


var joyStick = dc.barChart(composite)
    .dimension(joyTimeDimension)
    .colors('blue')
    .group(stepperGroup,"Joy Stick Movement")
    .keyAccessor(function(d) {return d.key[0];})
    .title( function(d){ 
        return [
            "Time: "+d.key[0],
            "Stepper Position: "+ d.value
        ].join('\n')
  });
  composite
    .width(1200)
    .transitionDuration(500)
    .margins({top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 25, left: 40})
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([startDate,currDate]))
    .xUnits(function(){return 150;})
    //.xUnits(d3.time.second)
    .elasticY(true)
    .legend(dc.legend().x(1000).y(4).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .renderTitle(true)
    .shareTitle(false)
    .compose([buttonPress, joyStick])
    .brushOn(false)
```

[image: Composite chart looks like this]

Is there a way to create a custom legend for this scenario?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let me provide a little bit of background about how the legend is built.

The legend in dc.js is really not all that sophisticated. It just calls `.legendables()` on the chart, and the chart decides what items to display in the legend.

Each chart has its own special-purpose code for this.

If we look at the [source for compositeChart.legendables()](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/d06bd9e6cefdd6a867370079bbc4205785b1e3f9/src/composite-chart.js#L480-L488), it's just recursively getting the legendables for each child chart and concatenating them:

```
_chart.legendables = function () {
    return _children.reduce(function (items, child) {
        if (_shareColors) {
            child.colors(_chart.colors());
        }
        items.push.apply(items, child.legendables());
        return items;
    }, []);
};
```

The pie chart [creates a legendable for each pie slice](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/d06bd9e6cefdd6a867370079bbc4205785b1e3f9/src/pie-chart.js#L570-L576):

```
_chart.legendables = function () {
    return _chart.data().map(function (d, i) {
        var legendable = {name: d.key, data: d.value, others: d.others, chart: _chart};
        legendable.color = _chart.getColor(d, i);
        return legendable;
    });
};
```

The legendables for the bar chart come from the stack mixin, which [creates a legendable for each stack](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/d06bd9e6cefdd6a867370079bbc4205785b1e3f9/src/stack-mixin.js#L311-L320):

```
_chart.legendables = function () {
    return _stack.map(function (layer, i) {
        return {
            chart: _chart,
            name: layer.name,
            hidden: layer.hidden || false,
            color: _chart.getColor.call(layer, layer.values, i)
        };
    });
};
```

Given that there's currently no way to get a bar chart to display a pie chart's legend, I think the easiest thing to do is override `legendables` for your bar chart with its custom colors:

```
buttonPress.legendables = function() {
    return btnGroup.all().map(function(kv) {
        return {
            chart: buttonPress,
            // display the value as the text (not sure what you want here)
            name: kv.value,
            // apply the chart's color scale to get the color
            color: buttonPress.colors()(kv.value)
        };
    })
};
```

There are probably some more details to be worked out, such as what if the same value occurs twice? I am assuming you can just read the input data from the group and `.map()` it, but you might need to generate your data a different way.

But this should give the general idea. Lmk if it doesn't work and I'll be glad to follow up.