# How to add legend for a bar chart with different colors in dc.js?

Tags: bar-chart, legend, dc.js

Below is the code snippet for a barchart with colored bars:

```
    var Dim2 = ndx.dimension(function(d){return [d.SNo, d.something ]});
    var Group2 = Dim2.group().reduceSum(function(d){ return d.someId; });
        
    var someColors = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8"])
.range(["#2980B9","#00FFFF","#008000","#FFC300","#FF5733","#D1AEF1","#C0C0C0","#000000"]);
        
         barChart2
                    .height(250)
                    .width(1000)
                    .brushOn(false)
                    .mouseZoomable(true)
                    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([600,800]))
                    .elasticY(false)
                    .dimension(Dim2)
                    .group(Group2)
                    .keyAccessor(function(d){ return d.key[0]; })
                    .valueAccessor(function(d){return d.value; })
                    .colors(someColors)
                    .colorAccessor(function(d){return d.key[1]; });
```

How do I add a legend to this chart?

[image: BarChart:]

Comment: You already asked the [same question for a bar chart within a composite chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47899515/custom-legend-based-on-color-of-bars-in-a-dc-js-composite-chart). Could you please try that out and see if it works?

Comment: I have tried that and the legend shows up, but it's not proper. Some values are repeating and some values don't appear at all. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I see. If you're able to post a self contained example, e.g. a jsfiddle, that would help folks troubleshoot it for you.

Comment: I have added the following code as you have suggested: barChart2.legendables = function() {
    return Group2.all().map(function(kv) {
     return {
      chart: barChart2,
      name: kv.key[1],
      color: barChart2.colors()(kv.key[1])
        };
       })
      };

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle with some sample data: https://jsfiddle.net/cod8hqwo/28/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using composite keys in crossfilter is really tricky, and I don't recommend it unless you really need it.

Crossfilter only understands scalars, so even though you can produce dimension and group keys which are arrays, and retrieve them correctly, crossfilter is going to coerce those arrays to strings, and that can cause trouble.

Here, what is happening is that `Group2.all()` iterates over your data in string order, so you get keys in the order

```
[1, "a1"], [10, "a3"], [11, "a4"], [12, "a5"], [2, "a3"], ...
```

Without changing the shape of your data, one way around this is to sort the data in your `legendables` function:

```
barChart2.legendables = function() { 
    return Group2.all().sort((a,b) => a.key[0] - b.key[0])
        .map(function(kv) { 
            return { 
                chart: barChart2, 
                name: kv.key[1], 
                color: barChart2.colors()(kv.key[1]) }; }) };
```

An unrelated problem is that dc.js takes the X domain very literally, so even though `[1,12]` contains all the values, the last bar was not shown because the right side ends right at 12 and the bar is drawn between 12 and 13.

So:

```
  .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([1,13]))
```

Now the legend matches the data!

[image: legend matches data[1]]

[Fork of your fiddle (also with dc.css)](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/47cb2ek0/4/).

**EDIT**: Of course, you want the legend items unique, too. You can define `uniq` like this:

```
function uniq(a, kf) {
    var seen = [];
    return a.filter(x => seen[kf(x)] ? false : (seen[kf(x)] = true));
}
```

Adding a step to `legendables`:

```
barChart2.legendables = function() { 
      var vals = uniq(Group2.all(), kv => kv.key[1]),
          sorted = vals.sort((a,b) => a.key[1] > b.key[1] ? 1 : -1);
          // or in X order: sorted = vals.sort((a,b) => a.key[0] - b.key[0]);
      return sorted.map(function(kv) { 
                    return { 
                        chart: barChart2, 
                        name: kv.key[1], 
                        color: barChart2.colors()(kv.key[1]) }; }) };
```

Note that we're sorting by the string value of `d.something` which lands in `key[1]`. As shown in the comment, sorting by x order (`d.SNo`, `key[0]`) is possible too. I wouldn't recommend sorting by y since that's a `reduceSum`.

Result, sorted and uniq'd:

[image: sorted and uniq'd]

[New fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/47cb2ek0/12/)

Comment: Thanks, @Gordon, for your inputs and your patience. I will keep your comments in mind.
Although this is good, my actual chart contains thousands of rows(bars), and I'm looking for a simple legend representing each color as shown in [figure](https://imgur.com/ETwm3rI). I apologize if my question wasn't clear earlier.