# How to add legend to dc.js row chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have a row chart that has been defined like this:

```
    rowChart    
            .width(768)
            .height(350)
            .dimension(typeDim,"typeDim")
            .group(countPerType,"countPerType")
            .label(function (d) {return ""})
            .ordering(function(d) { return d.countPerType })
            .cap(30)
```

I want the legend of this graph to be dynamic with a function but I am not sure if it is possible.

1. Is it possible to generate dynamic legends?
2. What should I add to my current rowChart to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Megha and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you provide a bit more detail on what you have tried so far, with error messages if available?

Comment: I have change  the wording of the problem so it also specifies 2 clear questions

Comment: if you create a `composeChart` you get a dynamic legend, it has the `.legend()` method

Comment: http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#legend__anchor

Comment: The row chart [does not currently support a legend](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/836). Adding it to a composite won't help because the bar chart also doesn't support composition because it is not a coordinate grid chart. This answer [shows how to add a legend to a chart which does not support it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47917844/676195)