# dc.js: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined when adding HtmlLegend to bar chart

Tags: javascript, typescript, dc.js

**Background**

I am trying to add an html legend to the dc.js bar chart as follows:

```
state.chart.legend(new dc.HtmlLegend().container(legendElement).horizontal(true).highlightSelected(true))
```

The chart is created as follows:

```
      const plotBarChart = (data: TrendTimeseries[], width: number) => {
        //@ts-ignore
        state.chart = new dc.BarChart(`#${ state.id }`);
        const barData = new Array<BarChartData>();
        data.forEach((value) => {
          if (value.Timeserie.length > 0 && value.Visible) {
            barData.push({
              Name: value.PlaceName,
              TruncateName: _.truncate(value.PlaceName, {
                length: 35,
                separator: ' ',
              }),
              //@ts-ignore
              Value: getDataByType(value.Timeserie[0]),
              Color: value.Color,
              Timestamp: value.Timeserie[0].timestamp,
            })
          }
        });
        const ndx = crossfilter(barData);
        const barDimension = ndx.dimension((d) => [d.TruncateName, d.Name, d.Timestamp]);
        const barGroup = barDimension.group().reduceSum((d) => d.Value);
        state.chart
          .dimension(barDimension)
          .group(barGroup)
          .renderTitle(false)
          .width(width)
          .height(280)
          .margins({
            top: 40,
            right: 40,
            bottom: 120,
            left: 40,
          })
          .x(d3.scaleBand())
          .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
          .brushOn(false)
          .transitionDuration(0)
          .barPadding(0.4)
          .outerPadding(0.2)
          //@ts-ignore
          .ordering((d) => {
            //@ts-ignore
            return priority(d.key[0]);
          })
          //@ts-ignore
          .colorAccessor((d) => d)
          //@ts-ignore
          .colors((d) => {
            return getBarColor(d.key[0], barData);
          });
```

**Problem**

The chart and the legend div are created, but the legend is not drawn, and the console shows an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

**Question**

What is the best way to add an html legend to the bar chart?

Comment: The legend for bar charts currently only works with the composite and stack features, not situations like this where you are coloring the bars individually within the same series. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47899515/custom-legend-based-on-color-of-bars-in-a-dc-js-composite-chart/47917844#47917844); while it has some unrelated information, it talks about how to customize `.legendables()` If you can't figure it out, please edit your question and add sample data and enough code to run your example, as well as the stack trace for the error you are getting.